# Picture encoded from android studio and decoding in python raspberry pi

Tags: android, python, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I want to communicate some text and pictures from Android app to Raspberry Pi...
I have already sent text messages and decoded perfectly..
But the problem is decoding the pictures...I'm getting the right decoding i think..

```
from socket import *
from time import ctime


ctrCmd = ['Up','Down']

HOST = ''
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZE = 1024
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
    print ('Waiting for connection')
    tcpCliSock,addr = tcpSerSock.accept()
    print ('...connected from :', addr)
    try:
            while True:
                    data = ''
                    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                    print(data)
                    data = str(data,encoding='utf-8')
                    if not data:
                            break
                    if data == ctrCmd[0]:
                            print ('Up')
                    if data == ctrCmd[1]:
                            print ('Down')
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
tcpSerSock.close();
```

and Here is the Android Encoding Code

```
imageUri = data.getData();
            final InputStream imageStream = 
getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
            final Bitmap selectedImage = 
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            selectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0, bos);
            array = bos.toByteArray();
```

These are the Android encoding and python decoding code pics
I'm sharing what i received while sending text and picture....
Will appreciate your help and i need it early....
Thanks

[picture of results what i receive at rpi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSr1x.jpg)

Comment: Please include all relevant code and information as **text**, not as an image.

Comment: I have attached 3 pictures ...Let me know if u want something else

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

```
data = ''
                    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZE)
                    #data = str(data,encoding='utf-8')
                    nparr = 
np.fromstring(data.decode('utf-8'),np.uint8)
                    print(nparr)
```

Applying this i got some arrays shown in attached picture 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPEbK.jpg)
But when i applied this line

```
#img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, 
cv2.IMREAD_ANYCOLOR)
```

It gives some errors and a list of None...See in attached picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvZVY.jpg)